# How can get nullable string value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, variables, nullable

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Login(string? returnUrl)
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        if(returnUrl.HasValue)
           return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        else
           return RedirectToAction(returnUrl);
    }
    return View();
}
```

[image]

> Error: The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Web.Mbv.Controller.Redirect(string)' has some invalid
>   arguments

How can use nullable string for  `RedirectToAction()`

Comment: `string` is _already_ nullable. `string?` doesn't make sense. What are you try to do exactly?

Comment: string is a reference type in c#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String is nullable already but you can check for null with string.IsNullOrEmpty.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
           if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
           {
               return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
           }
           else
           {
               return RedirectToAction(returnUrl);
           }
        }
        return View();
}
```

You could also default it so if it's not passed in it will never be empty.

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl = "www.yourDomain.com/login")
    {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
               return RedirectToAction(returnUrl);
            }
            return View();
    }
```